# When I have a pageReference that returns null, I lose my friendly url from urlRewriter

Tags: apex, visualforce, urlrewriter

When my controller returns null in a pageReference method, I lose my friendlyURL.

URLReWriter:

```
global without sharing class URLRewriter implements Site.UrlRewriter {

    global PageReference mapRequestUrl(PageReference myOriginalUrl){
        String url = myOriginalUrl.getUrl();
        String name;
        system.debug('Orginal URL is: '+url);
        if(url.equalsignorecase('/RSAP/help')){
            name = 'PBS_AAAP_Help';
        } else if(url.equalsignorecase('/RSAP/Help?Type=lop')){
            name = 'PBS_AAAP_Help?Type=lop';
        } else if(url.equalsIgnoreCase('/RSAP/UserRegistration')) {
            name = 'PBS_AAAP_UserRegistration';
        } else if(url.equalsIgnoreCase('/RSAP/userprofile?Type=lop')){
            name = 'PBS_AAAP_UserProfile?Type=lop';
        } else if(url.equalsIgnoreCase('/RSAP/UserProfile')) {
            name = '/PBS_AAAP_UserProfile';
        } else if(url.startsWithIgnoreCase('/AAAP/LOP_offerform1364')) {
            name = url.remove('/AAAP');
        } else if(url.startsWithIgnoreCase('/AAAP/LOP_offerform1217')) {
            name = url.remove('/AAAP');
        } else if(url.startsWithIgnoreCase('/AAAP/') && !url.contains('PBS_AAAP_')){
            name = url.remove('/AAAP/');
            name = '/PBS_AAAP_'+name;
        } else if (url.startsWithIgnoreCase('/RSAP/')){
            name = url.remove('/RSAP/');
            name = 'PBS_LOP_'+name;
        }  else {
            name = url;
        }
        system.debug('Final name is: '+name);
        PageReference pr = new PageReference(name);
        system.debug('PageReference is: '+name);
        return pr;
    }
    global List<PageReference> generateUrlFor(List<PageReference> mySalesforceUrls){
        return mySalesforceUrls;
    }
}
```

When this piece of code executes:

```
if (offerattachment.PBS_AAAP_Attachment_Type__c == null) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, 'Attachment Type is required.'));
            return null;  
        }
```

it shows the error, but I lose my friendly URL. If I handle the URL explicitly in the rewriter class, then I lose the error msg. Is there any way I can show the error without losing the friendly URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just closing the loop here.. I ended up using jQuery to detect unfriendly URLs and make them friendly on the page.